# CakePHP database queries in for loop

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My code is below. I have an array, and by using this array I fill the database table. If some id exists in table, I update its row, if id doesn't exist than I create row and write data to row.

I empty my table and then run this code:

```
$arrayOfIds=array('1234', '5678');

foreach ($arrayOfIds as $twitter_user_id) {
    $this->ModelName->twitter_user_id = $twitter_user_id;
    if ($this->ModelName->exists()) {
        echo "$twitter_user_id exists<br>";
    } else {
        echo "$twitter_user_id not exists<br>";
        $this->ModelName->create( array ('twitter_user_id' => $twitter_user_id));
    }

    $data = array(
        'ModelName' => array(
            'age' => 15,
            'last_status' => 'online'
        ));

    $this->ModelName->save($data);
}
```

Result is echoed to screen:
1234 not exists
5678 exists

When I check table, 2 rows (twitter_user_id =1234 and twitter_user_id =5678) was added to table.

When I re-run my code with two entries in table, I also get this response:
1234 not exists
5678 exists

Do I miss something?

Comment: Unless you're using a model from a plugin (a Twitter one perhaps?) and you're not showing it, it should be `$this->ModelName->id` to check if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that exists() function is working not like you are thinking it must be :)

i would change this line:

```
if ($this->ModelName->exists()) {
```

to something like this:

```
if ($this->ModelName->find()) {
```

and if its not working as needed, add some condition to find function.. about your twitter_user_id

Comment: Yes, find() doesn't solve. I solved the problem with this: **$exists=$this->ModelName->find('all', array( 'conditions' => array('ModelName.twitter_user_id' => $twitter_user_id) ));**